How to interconect a SQLServer Container and a different Spring Boot container
I have to different containers, a SQLServer container and a Spring Boot application.
If I execute the SQLServer container and run the Spring Boot application outside the container they connect, but when I create the Spring Boot container it fails.
This is the error:
2024-06-27 14:34:06 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

2024-06-27 14:34:06 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:231)

2024-06-27 14:34:06 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.convertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:282)

I have an example using mySql working (with two containers), but with SQLServer it fails. This are the steps I follow to run both containers:
I create a network for the communication
docker network create wcas-network

I run my SQLServer container (after it I create tables and data):
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Password!" -p 1433:1433 --network wcas-network --name sqlserver -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest

Then I run my Spring Boot container:
mvn clean install -DskipTests
docker build -t wcas .
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --network wcas-network --name wcas wcas

And then I see the error I attached and as I said, if I run locally my Spring Boot application it works. With a sqlServer client (like Heidi) I can connect and see the data fine too.

You have spring.datasource.url set to localhost, so the application container is trying to connect to itself.  Both containers are on the same Docker network, so you need to use the other container's name as the hostname.  Try adding -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:sqlserver://sqlserver and see if that helps?

Oh, in fact I did an example with mysql working and I forgot. It's working, thankyou. https://github.com/sergio-practices/mysql_practices/blob/main/mysql-dockerize/src/main/resources/application.properties
